# Aun soy novato pero tengo una duda con un array y un ciclo while quiero recorrer el array

Tags: c++

Quiero recorrer un Array en un bucle *while* el problema es que no puedo, y lo que necesito es que con cada vuelta que de el *while*, el array cambie a la siguiente posicion.

```c
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int i,nivel,hrs,hextra,dias, trabajador=1;
    double subtotal,total,Sueldoneto,totalneto;
    double Sneto[4];
    i=1;
    
    while(i<=5){
        cout<<"Trabajador: "<<trabajador<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingresar la categoria del empleado (1-3)"<<endl;
        cin>>nivel;
        cout<<"Ingresar los dias trabajados"<<endl;
        cin>>dias;
        if(nivel==1){
            subtotal=dias*1000;
            cout<<"Ingresar el numero de horas extra"<<endl;
            cin>>hrs;
            if(hrs>=20){
            hextra=hrs*120;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"Subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"Sueldo de horas extra:$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"Total:$"<<total<<endl;
        }
        else if(hrs>=10 && hrs<=20){
            hextra=hrs*100;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"sueldo de horas extra :$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"Total:$"<<total<<endl;
        }
        else if(hrs<10){
            hextra=hrs*90;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"Subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"Sueldo de las horas extra:$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"Total:$"<<total<<endl;
        }
        }
        else if(nivel==2){
        subtotal=dias*900;
        cout<<"Ingresar numero de horas extras"<<endl;
        cin>>hrs;
        if(hrs>=20){
            hextra=hrs*120;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"sueldo de horas extra:$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"total"<<total<<endl;
        }
        else if(hrs>=10 && hrs<=20){
            hextra=hrs*100;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"sueldo horas extra:$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"Total:$"<<total<<endl;
        }
        else if(hrs<10){
            hextra=hrs*90;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"sueldo horas extra:$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"Total:$"<<total<<endl;
        }
    }
    else if(nivel==3){
        subtotal=dias*700;
        cout<<"Ingrese el numero de horas extras"<<endl;
        cin>>hrs;
        if(hrs>=20){
            hextra=hrs*120;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"Sueldo horas extra:$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"Total:$"<<total<<endl;
        }
        else if(hrs>=10 && hrs<=20){
            hextra=hrs*100;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"sueldo horas extra:$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"Total:$"<<total<<endl;
        }
        else if(hrs<10){
            hextra=hrs*90;
            total=subtotal+hextra;
            cout<<"subtotal:$"<<subtotal<<endl;
            cout<<"sueldo horas extra:$"<<hextra<<endl;
            cout<<"Total:$"<<total<<endl;
        }
    }
    if(total>=20000){
        Sneto[0]=total+(total*0.15);
    }
    else if(total>=15000 && total<=20000){
        Sneto[0]=total+(total*0.12);
    }
    else if(total <15000){
        Sneto[0]=total+(total*0.09);
        
        
    }
    i++;
    trabajador++;
    
    cout<<"===================================="<<endl;
            
    }
    cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 1 "<<Sneto[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 2 "<<Sneto[1]<<endl;
    cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 3 "<<Sneto[2]<<endl;
    cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 4 "<<Sneto[3]<<endl;
    cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 5 "<<Sneto[4]<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esto tienes que crear una variable que te sirva de indice, luego al final de cada iteracion incrementala para que sigas recorriendo tu arreglo:

```
if(total>=20000){
    Sneto[i]=total+(total*0.15); //Reemplaza el 0 por i en tus indices
}
else if(total>=15000 && total<=20000){
    Sneto[i]=total+(total*0.12); //Reemplaza el 0 por i en tus indices
}
else if(total <15000){
    Sneto[i]=total+(total*0.09); //Reemplaza el 0 por i en tus indices
    
    
}
i++;
trabajador++;

cout<<"===================================="<<endl;
        
}
cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 1 "<<Sneto[0]<<endl;
cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 2 "<<Sneto[1]<<endl;
cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 3 "<<Sneto[2]<<endl;
cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 4 "<<Sneto[3]<<endl;
cout<<"Sueldo neto trabajador 5 "<<Sneto[4]<<endl;

return 0;
}
```